# Convert one agent to multiple agents in anylogic software

Tags: split, simulation, anylogic, processmodel, zinc

How can I convert one agent to multiple(more than 2) new agents in AnyLogic software?
For example, consider a  process of Zinc Smelting. In the roasting stage, the concentrate is converted into zinc calcine, sulfur dioxide, and other residue.

Using split block ,I can only convert one agent to the **same agent** and only **one** other agent...

Answer (score 0):

You can always create new agents using a population for the new agent type and adding to it with `add_MyAgentPopulation()`.

If this new agent needs to enter a flow again, you can send them to any point using an "Enter" block with `myEnterBlock.take(agent)` where `agent` would be the agent you created above

Comment: I want to convert one agent to 3 new agents with different types (not 3 agents of one type) during a process.
how can this  implemented in anylogic?

Comment: As I said above, this is the way. Learn about agent populations and instantiation as well as Enter blocks, then the answer will make sense :)